# PHP ob_end_clean does not work

Tags: php

ob_end_clean does not clear buffer:

```
if (ob_get_level() == 0) 
     ob_start(null, 0, PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE ^ PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_REMOVABLE);

 echo '<div id="spinner">Loading...</div>';  
 ob_flush();
 flush();
 ob_end_clean();
```

Do I do something wrong?

Comment: Why not use ob_end_flush()?

Comment: ob_end_flush() instead of ob_end_clean()? Tried it, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide the option to **ob_start** that allows you to flush the buffer, i.e. **PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_FLUSHABLE** is missing.

But, the default for these options is already set well according to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php):

> The **flags** parameter is a bitmask that controls the operations that can be performed on the output buffer. The default is to allow output buffers to be cleaned, flushed and removed, which can be set explicitly via **PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE | PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_FLUSHABLE | PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_REMOVABLE**, or **PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_STDFLAGS** as shorthand.

So just leave out the flags argument. BTW, the other arguments were specified with their default value, so you can leave them out as well:

```
if (ob_get_level() == 0) 
    ob_start(); // use defaults for all arguments.

echo '<div id="spinner">Loading...</div>';  
ob_end_flush(); // this does a clean as well
flush();
```

Note that cleaning the buffer does not wipe out what you have already flushed. Whatever is flushed appears in the browser and is no longer under the control of PHP. It is up to your client code (JavaScript) to further manipulate such output and/or redirect the user to another page.

Comment: But it doesnt work. The "Loading..." just stays there.

Comment: @Totallama The server can't remove something the client has already received. If you want to remove the spinner div _after_ it's been sent, the client needs to manipulate the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model): `<script type="text/javascript">var spinner = document.getElementById('spinner'); spinner.parentNode.removeChild(spinner)</script>"`

Comment: Clearing the buffer is not about wiping out what is already sent to the browser. Clearing the buffer makes you start with a clean buffer for future buffering. Whatever you send (flush) to the browser is no longer under control by PHP. Just as difficult as taking back a spoken word.

Comment: I see.. But if I first insert <div id="spinner">Loading...</div> using ob_flush and then try to delete it with js, the whole page gets cleared out for some reason..

Comment: Maybe I need to flush also all the stuff like DOCTYPE, <head> and other stuff

Comment: Good to hear. Good job!

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please accept it :)